# MySQL получить отдельным полем справочник "ключ-значение" как JSON

Tags: словари, json, join, mysql

Что-то торможу :(
Есть два сложных запроса

1) Получает основной список записей

```
SELECT 
b_iblock_element.id, 
b_iblock_element.`name`, 
b_iblock_element.preview_text, 
b_iblock_element.detail_text, 
b_iblock_element.detail_picture,
b_catalog_price.price,
b_catalog_product.quantity
FROM b_iblock_element
LEFT JOIN b_catalog_price ON b_catalog_price.PRODUCT_ID = b_iblock_element.id
LEFT JOIN b_catalog_product ON b_catalog_product.ID = b_iblock_element.id
WHERE ( b_iblock_element.iblock_id = '6') -- AND (b_iblock_element.id in ({combinationsIds}));
```

2) Получает словарь "ключ-значение" для заданного iblock_element_id = b_iblock_element.id

```
SELECT CONCAT('{', GROUP_CONCAT(feature), '}') as features FROM 
(
SELECT CONCAT_WS(':', QUOTE(`value`), QUOTE(`name`)) as feature
FROM b_iblock_element_property 
INNER JOIN b_iblock_property 
ON (b_iblock_element_property.IBLOCK_PROPERTY_ID = b_iblock_property.ID)
AND (iblock_element_id='28478')
) f
```

Как объединить этот ужас, чтобы второй запрос прилетал как поле features со всеми полями первого запроса?

%%%%%%%%% Решено, ответить на свой вопрос не могу, т.к. кармы не хватает %%%%%%%%%

Получился вот такой не хилый запрос. Осталось сообразить, как его оптимизировать, потому что в плане производительности он кошмарен

```
SELECT 
b_iblock_element.id, 
b_iblock_element.`name`, 
b_iblock_element.preview_text, 
b_iblock_element.detail_text, 
b_iblock_element.detail_picture,
b_catalog_price.price,
b_catalog_product.quantity, 
featuresToJson.features
FROM b_iblock_element
LEFT JOIN b_catalog_price ON b_catalog_price.PRODUCT_ID = b_iblock_element.id
LEFT JOIN b_catalog_product ON b_catalog_product.ID = b_iblock_element.id
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT iblock_element_id, CAST(CONCAT('{', GROUP_CONCAT(feature), '}') AS CHAR) as features FROM 
    (
        SELECT b_iblock_element_property.iblock_element_id, CONCAT_WS(':', QUOTE(b_iblock_element_property.IBLOCK_PROPERTY_ID), QUOTE(b_iblock_element_property.`value`)) as feature
        FROM b_iblock_element_property 
        ORDER BY b_iblock_element_property.iblock_element_id, feature
    ) featuresTable
    GROUP BY iblock_element_id
) featuresToJson
ON featuresToJson.iblock_element_id = b_iblock_element.ID
WHERE ( b_iblock_element.iblock_id = '6')
ORDER BY b_iblock_element.ID
```

Comment: Может не стоит лезть в ядро битрикс? И пользоваться API для запросов.

Answer (score 1):

Работать нужно не только с битриксом, более того код CMS вообще трогать нельзя, к тому же не все CMS имеют нормальное API для работы, а Bitrix к тому же ещё и как-то извращённо смотрится после OpenCart, PrestaShop и прочих, нет даже желания в его потрохах (это какое-то наследие тяжёлых 90-ых) разбираться ради одной нормальной выборки.